# Graphics using plot.mc

Tags: r

I need help with some of the graphics on a cumulative distribution plot using plot.mc

An example of what I am doing is as follows:

```
Require(mc2d)
ndvar(10000)
test<-mcstoc(rbetagen,type="V",shape1=48, shape2=66.42, min=0, max=4000)
hist(test)
test<-mc(test)
plot(test)
```

This plots the cumulative distribution of "test".

What I want to do, is draw a verticle line up from a specific point on the x-axis (say 1800), which touches the cumulative distribution line, then draws a line across to the Y axis at the point corresponding to 1800 on the x axis.

I have looked up help(plot.mc) and help(plot.stepfun) but neither seem to be able to do this.

Many thanks,

Timothy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?arrows`

```
plot(test)
arrows(x0=0, y0=.745, x1=1800, y1=.745, code=0, lty=2)
arrows(x0=1800, y0=0, x1=1800, y1=.745, code=0, lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: And how did you calculate the 0.745 for the Y value? This is exactly what I was looking for though, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I didn't calculate it, it is an arbitrary number. But I think looking inside `test` you could find the right number. Glad to be useful.